# Botframework-directlinejs error on Next.JS 14

Tags: next.js, botframework, next.js14

I'm trying to use the  Component in a page.tsx (I'm using 'use client' for client side rendering) but it always returns this error:

```
 ⨯ ./node_modules/errlop/edition-browsers/index.js
Module parse failed: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module' (13:0)
|     /* eslint no-use-before-define:0 */ return value instanceof Error || Errlop.isErrlop(value);
| }
> export default class Errlop extends Error {
|     /**
|        * Create an instance of an error, using a message, as well as an optional parent.

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/errlop/edition-browsers/index.js
./node_modules/editions/edition-es5/index.js
./node_modules/istextorbinary/index.js
./node_modules/async-disk-cache/index.js
./node_modules/microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk/distrib/lib/src/common.browser/CertChecks.js
./node_modules/microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk/distrib/lib/src/common.browser/WebsocketMessageAdapter.js
./node_modules/microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk/distrib/lib/src/common.browser/Exports.js
./node_modules/botframework-webchat/lib/speech/createMicrophoneAudioConfigAndAudioContext.js
./node_modules/botframework-webchat/lib/createCognitiveServicesSpeechServicesPonyfillFactory.js
./node_modules/botframework-webchat/lib/index.js
./app/digital-assistant/page.tsx
```

Here is the code for the page.tsx

```
'use client';

import { DirectLine } from 'botframework-directlinejs';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';

const ReactWebChat = dynamic(
    () => {
        return import('botframework-webchat');
    },
    {
        ssr: false,
    }
);
export default function DigitalAssistantPage() {
    const [directLineToken, setDirectLineToken] = useState<DirectLine | string>(
        ''
    );
    useEffect(() => {
        if (directLineToken != '') {
            axios
                .post(
                    'https://directline.botframework.com/api/tokens/conversation',
                    {},
                    {
                        headers: {
                            Authorization:
                                'Bearer REDACTED',
                        },
                    }
                )
                .then((res: any) => {
                    setDirectLineToken(new DirectLine({ token: res.data }));
                });
        }
    }, [directLineToken]);

    if (directLineToken == '') {
        return <>Fetching Token...</>;
    }
    return <ReactWebChat directLine={directLineToken} />;
}
```

I think the problem is mostly generating from the createDirectLineSpeechServices but I'm not using it in the first place, I tried even commenting them in the index.ts but that also didn't work